# PDF viewer for Windows 32-bit that can hide wide margins

Tags: pdf, fullscreen, pdf-reader

I view a lot of PDFs on my wide display (1280x800).

I want to view books with two pages on screen at once, but some PDFs have *huge* margins, so only ~60-70% of screen space is used even if I hide the menubar and toolbar in Acrobat Reader.

Are there any PDF viewers available which can cancel wide margins (hide them)? I will have a bigger font and higher usage of my screen area.

**Requirements:**

- Windows 32-bit
- Ability of view mode "Two-Up"/"Facing" (the two pages are viewed side-by-side, second is left from first)
- Full-screen or "no toolbars" mode
- Hiding of wide margins (with scaling of pages, no reflow needed; automatic or easy configuration of margins size)
- Easy scrolling available (when I press a space, show the exactly next pair of pages; not the bottom part of current pages)
- I need a viewer, not a PDF crop utility (PDF files must be kept in original form)

**Already tested** (they can't do what I want or I can't find the needed mode):

- Acrobat Reader 9
- Foxit Reader
- STDU Viewer
- Sumatra PDF  (it tries, but it doesn't hide the margins, and the "Fit content" mode with two pages side-by-side does resizing wrong sometimes)

Comment: The only PDF viewer I know of that does this is Okular. I suppose you *could* use it on Windows if you install [KDE for Windows](http://windows.kde.org/), but that might be overkill.

Comment: How huge download (100s MB or several GB) will it be to install Okular and its dependence?

Comment: As http://okular.kde.org/formats.php says, Okular uses poppler to render pdf. Can the poppler do the task?

Comment: I didn't try yet, but according to this http://biblprog.org.ua/en/pdf_xchange_viewer/historychanges/#ixzz2g4l8YYNS
 PDF-XChange Viewer 2.0.52.0 Added comment "Remove White Spaces" which removes whites spaces (margins) on a document's pages. By default this command available only via customization options.

Comment: Have you tried Acrobat's most up to date viewer, [DC](https://acrobat.adobe.com/us/en/acrobat/pdf-reader.html), as Acrobat 9 is ancient (close to a decade old)?

Comment: @osgx Not anymore. See latest answer.

Answer (score 1):

Okular will trim margins. Here is the last version built for Windows 32-bit, which can be installed with Chocolatey: https://chocolatey.org/packages/okular/19.03.90

Comment: Latest version for 64-bit: https://chocolatey.org/packages/okular Precompiled binary is obtained from [KDE CI build artifacts](https://binary-factory.kde.org/job/Okular_Release_win64/lastStableBuild/).

Answer (score 0):

There are some PDF editors which can remove the margins from a PDF. I use [Nitro PDF](http://www.nitropdf.com/), but it's not free. I think there are some free ones that can do the same thing.

Comment: The question says "I need a viewer, not an pdf crop utility"

Comment: If I can't have a viewer with margin-ignoring, I could build a "copy_pdf - remove_margin - open_in_viewer" process. Is the margin removing automatic or manual? Can I script this?

Comment: For automatic cropping, you could use either sopdf or a combination of ghostscript and calibre Details [here](http://www.charlietanksley.net/philtex/reading-pdfs-on-portables/#crop). There's also the [pdfcrop](http://pdfcrop.sourceforge.net/) perl script.

Comment: There is another converter:  "`pdftk $1 burst`; convert -trim +repage $p $p" http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/ebooks/130308/